# Mongo connection occasionally makes the lambda function timeout

Tags: mongodb, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I have been using MLab MongoDB and mongoose library to create a db connection inside a serverless (Lambda) handler. It works smoothly on local machine. But sometimes it doesn't work after deployment.The request returns an `Internal server error`. The weird thing is sometimes it works. But If I remove the database connection code, the handler works. The serverless log just says `Process exited before completing request`. No real errors so no idea what to do.

The db connection looks like this:
handler.js

```
// Connect to database
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  useMongoClient: false
}).then((ee) => {
  console.log('------------------------invoke db ', ee);
})
  .catch(err => console.error('-----------error db ', err));
```

No error in here too. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Increase the timeout, add xray tracing, find out which bit is slow. Then after the lambda is warm, look at the tracing again.

Comment: @TrentBartlem Still didn't help :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get `Process exited before completing request`, it means that the `node` process has crashed before Lambda was able to call `callback`. If you go to Cloudwatch logs, there would be an error and stack trace of what happened.

You should connect to the MongoDB instance *inside your handler* and before you call `callback()`, disconnect first.

It would be like this...

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let response;

  return mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useMongoClient: false
  }).then((ee) => {
    // prepare your response
    response = { hello: 'world' }
  }).then(() => {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }).then(() => {
    // Success
    callback(null, response)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);

    callback(err);
  })
};
```

Comment: connection should NOT be inside the handler, neither disconnected (generally) after usage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@cbernardes/serverless-things-i-wish-i-had-known-part-2-dynamodb-x-mongodb-x-aurora-serverless-1053cfddff36) explaining with details how lambda work with node and an example of how to implement DB connection.
Differently of @dashmug suggested, you should NOT disconnect your DB since connecting every time will decrease your performance.